# Google Street View with Filemaker Pro Web View

Tags: google-maps, filemaker, google-street-view

I am currently using Filemaker Pro 12, and with web view I have written functions to automatically grab information from the address fields in each record to call up both Google Maps and Google Satellite (Aerial) for each record.

The problem I have is with street view.  The following is the function that I am using for Street View:
"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=37.35302269,-122.01458914&cbp=12,72.73,,0,-6.2&output=svembed"

It works great, but I would like to be able to point the x and y coordinates fields in each record so that I do not need to enter them for each record.  The Field Names are Retail Database::Y Coordinate and Retail Database::X Coordinate

Again, I was able to write functions for Google Maps and Satellite but can't seem to for Google Street View.  Please Help.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a simple calc which drops the field into the URL string.

"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=" & Retail Database::Y Coordinate & "," & Retail Database::X Coordinate & "&cbp=12,72.73,,0,-6.2&output=svembed"